# How to pass a parameter into an https function when it's called from swift?

Tags: node.js, swift, typescript, stripe-payments

I've been implementing stripe into my app with typescript and I have the following function:

```
exports.deleteStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => { 
  const deleted = await stripe.customers.del(
    "I need to add the customers ID here"
  );
});
```

In that string where I need to add the customerID, I would like to add the customer ID from my swift code where I'm already listening for that ID and add it to the function when it's called.

In swift this would be done like this:

```
func sayHello(name: string) {
    print("hello \(name)")
}
```

and then when the function is called the id is passed in from somewhere else like this:

```
sayHello(name: usersName)
```

any idea how this is done in typescript?

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TypeScript function, you would simply get it from the `data` parameter.

```
exports.deleteStripeCustomer = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    const userId = data.userId
});
```

And in the Swift call, you would pass it like so:

```
let payload = [
    "userId": "u456"
]

SomeAPI.httpsCallable("deleteStripeCustomer").call(payload) { (_, error) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

I've never worked with Stripe and I don't know how their client-side API is configured (or server-side for that matter) but I assume it's like other TypeScript-Swift inter-operations I've worked with in the past and this is how it's done there. If you link me to their documentation about this API I can help further but generally, since you asked generally, this is how it's done.